# How to SUM all subchildren tree in SQL recursively?

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query, children

Good day, I've been pulling my hair on this problem for a while ><"

I have **4 categories** in a tree structure.

*tenant_category_transaction_view:*

[image]

### I would like to have the sum of all children "sumSubtotal" on every category

Something like that:
[image]

I've managed to come very close... But there's something I don't get ><"

```
with recursive cte (sumSubtotal, sumQuantity, id, idParentCategory, treeSum, depth) as (

        select  root.sumSubtotal, -- STEP 1
                root.sumQuantity, 
                root.id, 
                root.idParentCategory, 
                root.sumSubtotal as treeSum,
                0 as depth
        from    tenant_category_transaction_view as root

        union all -- LOOP THROUGH ALL ROOT ROWS AND ADD ROWS TO THE CTE WITH THE INNER JOIN

        select  child.sumSubtotal, -- STEP 3
                child.sumQuantity, 
                child.id, 
                child.idParentCategory, 
                (cte.treeSum + child.sumSubtotal) AS treeSum,
                (cte.depth + 1) AS depth
        from    tenant_category_transaction_view AS child

        inner join cte on child.idParentCategory = cte.id -- STEP 2
)
select sumSubtotal, sumQuantity, id, idParentCategory, treeSum, depth -- STEP 4
from cte
```

Result of the above query:

[image]

It seems I'm generating the correct treeSum but upside down in only one branch

Would you be so kind to give me a hand?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: In your opinion, you should use group by

Comment: The problem with your approach: it sums in the wrong direction, with the current subtotal being this_value plus the parent.subtotal.  That produces the reversed partial totals you see.  Also notice your grand total is missing, because of the same problem.

Comment: You've changed the test case to not link the two top level categories through a common non-null root.  You should have a top level category / root to allow them to be aggregated, just as I've shown in my answer.  It's inconvenient if you have a special null case which needs to be aggregated separately.  Just a suggestion.  ... and, of course, without correct detail in the question, I placed values in different columns.  I'll adjust that.

Comment: In case you aren't able to adjust your current data to remove the null issues, I've updated my answer to work with your existing data.  The answer contains SQL to solve that direct problem you asked, as well as a suggested change at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've updated the fiddle to include the exact schema / data provided in the question, including the null issues.  It also includes an example of my suggested changes.

The solution basically takes the given data and transforms it internally (in the CTE term `nodes`) so that the 2 top level category rows link to a common row, with id 0, so that the original logic I provided can be used to treat this as one hierarchical list of categories.

First, we find all the branch lists recursively.  Each branch is identified by a corresponding root.  Then, we aggregate the node quantities for each root/branch.

[The fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=73edf1a3b92bd4e5ba3333f985deb031)

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE nodes AS (
         SELECT id, COALESCE(idParentCategory, 0) AS idParentCategory
              , sumSubtotal, sumQuantity
           FROM tenant_category_transaction_view
          UNION
         SELECT 0, null, 0, 0
     )
   , cte AS (
        SELECT t.*, t.id AS root
             , idParentCategory AS idParentCategory0
             , sumSubtotal      AS sumSubtotal0
             , sumQuantity      AS sumQuantity0
          FROM nodes AS t
         UNION ALL
        SELECT t.* , t0.root
             , t0.idParentCategory0
             , t0.sumSubtotal0
             , t0.sumQuantity0
          FROM cte AS t0
          JOIN nodes AS t
            ON t.idParentCategory = t0.id
     )
SELECT root
     , MIN(idParentCategory0)   AS idParentCategory
     , MIN(sumSubtotal0)        AS sumSubtotal
     , MIN(sumQuantity0)        AS sumQuantity
     , SUM(t1.sumSubtotal)      AS total
  FROM cte AS t1
 GROUP BY root
 ORDER BY root
;
```

The result:

| root | idParentCategory | sumSubtotal | sumQuantity | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | null | 0 | 0 | 9890 |
| 1 | 0 | 9800 | 98 | 9800 |
| 4 | 0 | 20 | 1 | 90 |
| 5 | 4 | 30 | 1 | 70 |
| 6 | 5 | 40 | 1 | 40 |

The setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tenant_category_transaction_view (
    id               int primary key
  , idParentCategory int
  , sumSubtotal      int
  , sumQuantity      int
);

INSERT INTO tenant_category_transaction_view VALUES
    (1, null, 9800, 98)
  , (4, null,   20,  1)
  , (5,    4,   30,  1)
  , (6,    5,   40,  1)
;
```

The following uses a suggested slight adjustment to the original table and data.  Instead of the 2 top null parent references for rows with id 1 and 4, add a top row (with id 99, for instance) and let rows with id 1 and 4 refer to that with parent = 99.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
        SELECT t.*, t.id AS root
          FROM tenant_category_transaction_view AS t
         UNION ALL
        SELECT t.*, t0.root
          FROM cte AS t0
          JOIN tenant_category_transaction_view AS t
            ON t.idParentCategory = t0.id
     )
SELECT root
     , MIN(t2.idParentCategory) AS idParentCategory
     , MIN(t2.sumSubtotal)      AS sumSubtotal
     , MIN(t2.sumQuantity)      AS sumQuantity
     , SUM(t1.sumSubtotal)      AS total
  FROM cte AS t1
  JOIN tenant_category_transaction_view AS t2
    ON t1.root = t2.id
 GROUP BY root
 ORDER BY root
;
```

The result:

| root | idParentCategory | sumSubtotal | sumQuantity | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 99 | null | 0 | 0 | 9890 |
| 1 | 99 | 9800 | 98 | 9800 |
| 4 | 99 | 20 | 1 | 90 |
| 5 | 4 | 30 | 1 | 70 |
| 6 | 5 | 40 | 1 | 40 |

Additionally, this can be written to aggregate based on t2.id, which is the primary key, allowing slight simplification, due to functional dependence.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
        SELECT t.*, t.id AS root
          FROM tenant_category_transaction_view AS t
         UNION ALL
        SELECT t.*, t0.root
          FROM cte AS t0
          JOIN tenant_category_transaction_view AS t
            ON t.idParentCategory = t0.id
     )
SELECT t2.id
     , t2.idParentCategory
     , t2.sumSubtotal
     , t2.sumQuantity
     , SUM(t1.sumSubtotal)      AS total
  FROM cte AS t1
  JOIN tenant_category_transaction_view AS t2
    ON t1.root = t2.id
 GROUP BY t2.id
 ORDER BY t2.id
;
```

Finally, we can remove the last JOIN by carrying other root values within the recursive logic:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
        SELECT t.*, t.id AS root
             , idParentCategory AS idParentCategory0
             , sumSubtotal      AS sumSubtotal0
             , sumQuantity      AS sumQuantity0
          FROM tenant_category_transaction_view AS t
         UNION ALL
        SELECT t.* , t0.root
             , t0.idParentCategory0
             , t0.sumSubtotal0
             , t0.sumQuantity0
          FROM cte AS t0
          JOIN tenant_category_transaction_view AS t
            ON t.idParentCategory = t0.id
     )
SELECT root
     , MIN(idParentCategory0)   AS idParentCategory
     , MIN(sumSubtotal0)        AS sumSubtotal
     , MIN(sumQuantity0)        AS sumQuantity
     , SUM(t1.sumSubtotal)      AS total
  FROM cte AS t1
 GROUP BY root
 ORDER BY root
;
```

The setup:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tenant_category_transaction_view;
CREATE TABLE tenant_category_transaction_view (
    id               int primary key
  , idParentCategory int
  , sumSubtotal      int
  , sumQuantity      int
);

INSERT INTO tenant_category_transaction_view VALUES
    (99, null,    0,  0)
  , ( 1,   99, 9800, 98)
  , ( 4,   99,   20,  1)
  , ( 5,    4,   30,  1)
  , ( 6,    5,   40,  1)
;
```

Comment: Jesus @Jon Armstrong you crushed my question, I was about to throw my computer by the window hahah Well done!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is actually quite simple :-)

1. Inside the CTE add an hard-coded row that represents the root node (where id is NULL). Please note that we can use multiple anchore queries within a CTE (queries that does not refer to the name of the CTE).
2. Create all paths from all node to all of their descendants (including themselves). Each path is represented by a row that holds the start node id, the descendant node id and the amount of the descendant node. Please note the use of the null-safe equal operator ([<=>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to))
3. Aggregate by the starting nodes ids and for each node summarize the amount of all of its descendants

P.S.
There is nothing recursive about "recursive" queries. It is a misleading name. Those are actually iterative queries, not recursive.

---

```
with recursive cte (root_id, id, sumSubtotal)  as 
(
  select     null
            ,null
            ,0
  
  union all
  
  select     id
            ,id
            ,sumSubtotal

  from      tenant_category_transaction_view as tctv
  
  union all
  
  select     cte.root_id
            ,tctv.id
            ,tctv.sumSubtotal

  from      cte 
            join    tenant_category_transaction_view as tctv 
            on      tctv.idParentCategory <=> cte.id
)
select   root_id
        ,sum(sumSubtotal)
from     cte
group by root_id
```

---

```
+---------+-------------+
| root_id | sumSubtotal |
+---------+-------------+
| null    |        9890 |
| 1       |        9800 |
| 4       |          90 |
| 5       |          70 |
| 6       |          40 |
+---------+-------------+
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b836c08560aab33672cabf21d09e09c2)

Comment: It works also, thank you for your quick answer @David דודו Markovitz !